# updates in __new__'s kwargs not making it to __init__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why can't I see "y" in init in the following example??

The exact same object is being passed to "init" but changes arent visible (deleting x in **new** will also have no effect )

```
class Object:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):

        print("O.new_pre", id(kwds), kwds)
        kwds["y"] = 11
        print("O.new_post", id(kwds), kwds)

        self = super().__new__(cls)
        return self
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        print("O.init", id(kwds), kwds)



obj = Object(x=10)
o.new_pre  140439785572928 {'x': 10}
o.new_post 140439785572928 {'x': 10, 'y': 11}
o.init     140439785572928 {'x': 10}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by complication of adding `__new__()` that couldn’t be achieved much more clearly by adding one line in `__init__()` i.e.`kwds[‘y’]=11`

Comment: @DisappointedByUnaccountableMod thats not the point.. how come changing the same dict object is not reflecting in __init__

Answer (score 0):

`__new__` is for the instance creation, `__init__` is for the initialization.
The changes you make to kwds in `__new__` are not being seen in `__init__`.

An approach to get what you are trying to achieve would could be with metaclasses

```
class Meta(type):

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("O.new_pre", id(kwargs), kwargs)
        kwargs["y"] = 11
        print("O.new_post", id(kwargs), kwargs)
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)


class A(metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        print("O.init", id(kwds), kwds)
```

which prints

```
O.new_pre 4341449208 {'x': 10}
O.new_post 4341449208 {'x': 10, 'y': 11}
O.init 4337539904 {'x': 10, 'y': 11}
```

Comment: What I don't understand is how the changes are not reflected when the same object is passed to both (same id())

Comment: Both init and new will be passed the same set of arguments exception made for the first one, but now I understand your doubt. Try to use `Object(x={'a':'10'})` and update `kwds["x"]['b'] = 2` in `__new__`.

Comment: @abc the point is not to make his code work.. rather than why it is not working? even both dictionaries has same ids

Answer (score 0):

I feel the other answers didnt attend the main intention of the question. By extending the author's question we may come to some conclusions.

You can see from the below output all the method's/function's kwargs (apart from dunder methods) have same ids. Since, we are not expecting the change in one of the kwarg will lead to changing the kwargs. So, we have to expect the same for **init** & **new** kwargs as well.

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['a'] = 10
        print("__new__ ", id(kwargs), kwargs)
        return super().__new__(cls)
        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("__init__", id(kwargs), kwargs)

        
    def inner_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("inner_func", id(kwargs), kwargs)
    
    def oinner_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("oinner_func", id(kwargs), kwargs)

def outer_func(*args, **kwargs):
    print("outer_func", id(kwargs), kwargs)

def oouter_func(*args, **kwargs):
    print("oouter_func", id(kwargs), kwargs)

a = A(a=100)
a.inner_func()
a.oinner_func()

outer_func()
oouter_func()

Output:
__new__  140698133074304 {'a': 10}
__init__ 140698133074304 {'a': 100}
inner_func 140698133838976 {}
oinner_func 140698133838976 {}
outer_func 140698133838976 {}
oouter_func 140698133838976 {}
```